# Add single quotes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have use inputted values in a variable in this format:

`ny,nj,ct`

and stored in this variable:

`$search_crit`

I then run the following

```
$list = explode(',', $search_crit);
array_map(array($dbh, 'quote'), $list);
$sql1 = sprintf('SELECT  `Provider Number`,`Number of Cases` FROM `mytable` where`color` = :colorpicked and `State` in (%s) group by `Provider Number`', implode(',', $list));
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':color', $colorSel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This works fine when I do a different query where instead of states, they are inputting zip codes, so I end up with something like this: `and 'zipcode' in (45040,45249)`. This works fine because they are numbers (I guess).

Back to my code above...if I try this with states like this: `and 'states' in (ny,nj,ct)` I get errors saying that `ny` isn't a column. If I can somehow run the query like this, it works: `and 'states' in ('ny','nj','ct')`.

What's the best approach here? Is there a simple way to insert the single quotes in PHP? Should I change the query to be able to accept a list (`ny,nj,ct`) of states that could be any number (e.g., 3 states or 15 states)?

Comment: You could `implode()` the list to include the quotes prior to using them in the `IN()`

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: `$newList = "('" .implode("','",$OLDLIST) ."')"`

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 Thanks. This got me going in the right direction. I changed a bit of my php too to not use the `sprintf` and just use the variable after your transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ryan_W4588 for pointing me in the right direction to prepare the variable. I had to change my PHP code a bit as well to accommodate this.

```
$list = explode(',', $search_crit);
$newList = "'" .implode("','",$list) ."'";
$sql1 = "SELECT  `Provider Number`,`Number of Cases` FROM `mytable` where`color` = :colorpicked and `State` in ({$newList}) group by `Provider Number`";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bindParam(':color', $colorSel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result1 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `:color` !== `:colorpicked`

Comment: @Rizier123 why `!==`, doesn't he want `=`? Other than that, good edit.

Comment: @Ryan_W4588 The placeholders haven't the same name

Comment: @Rizier123 I understand now, totally went over my head. You are saying they aren't equivalent, I thought you were editing his code directly. I apologize haha, you are right!

Comment: @Rizier123 Good catch. The sql was just an example though. In my actual code, I don't have placeholders with the same name.